# c assignment, types and source transformations

Tags: c, casting

I am writing some code (in python using pycparser) that does some editing of c (C99) language source code. It's supposed to find all assignment statements in the code and replace the rvalue with a function that prints the rvalue and immediately returns it.

For example, given the code:

```
int x;
x = 5;
```

the result will be:

```
int x;
x = myprint(5);
```

where myprint would be defined as

```
 int myprint(int k) {
     printf("%d",k);
     return k;
 }
```

thus, the value of x in the new code will be the same but running it will also print the assigned value.

Here's the question: In general, the type of the rvalue isn't as simple as an integer. What should the parameter and return types of myprint be?

In C, there's a type conversion during assignment such that the rvalue is cast to to type of the lvalue. There's another type conversion during function calls from the argument type to the parameter type. It seems to me that it doesn't matter if the parameter type and return type of myprint are both the rvalue's type or both the lvalue's type, as far as the value that ends in up in the variable on the left remains the same. Am I correct?

A small side question:

in a code such as this:

```
int ** p
(*p) = <something>
```

the rvalue would be cast to int *, right?

Thank you.

Comment: As you can also assign structs and other types, this will very soon become impossible to maintain. In fact, you need a function for all standard types and all compound types your program uses, not to forget about the qualified versions. Even worse, you will need to parse these types to print them. I honestly doubt it will be worth the effort, even if you only concentrate on the standard types.

Comment: Note that the type conversions will generate warnings if they are not safe (at least if you enable warnings - what you really should do!). Pointer casts are very dangerous - do not (in general)! And that has nothing to do with "static analysis". It is just about instrumentation.

Comment: pycparser is designed well, so the complexity doesn't grow as fast as it otherwise might. Also, the tool isn't supposed to be bulletproof. It's ok to fail sometimes, as long as it's not too often. But when the tool works, the result needs to be correct. Hence the original question.

Comment: You should first get deeper into C. There are quite some claims which do not hold about casting, etc. Either you use proper types for the functions, or you don't and provoke _undefined behaviour_. There are better things to do if you want to play with pycparser and manipulating source code than breaking possibly running code. This might sound harsh, but if you do right it is not worth the effort and if not, it will be of no actual use and break the code.

Comment: Can you elaborate on which claims don't hold? This tool is meant to be run on automatically generated code which is compiled with different optimizations to see if the compiler does something silly (it does. at times). However, the generated code can be quite complicated and long, so being able to narrow down the first place in the code where a different value appears (across optimizations) would help in narrowing down the issue

Comment: As I wrote, this is too broad. If your compiler generates wrong code, you should complain at the vendor or use a different one. (What else could you mean with "something silly"?). For what you are describing here, a debugger would be the perfect choice. Now it sounds even more like an XY-problem.

Comment: I'll rephrase. I'm specifically looking for compiler bugs, of which there are many. To do this, I use a fuzzer to generate C99 code without any undefined behaviour. compiling this code under different optimizations should result in binaries that compute the same values for variables, unless the compiler is buggy.

Once I have code that results in a compilation bug, the next question is which part of that code triggers the bug. To find this part, I'm writing the tool described in the original question